# How do you pass a variable to a Promise.All function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In the example below, I am trying to pass the `filter` const into the `Promise.all` function, but I can't figure out how to pass it down which is resulting in it being undefined in the last line.

How can I pass the variable into the `Promise.all` function?

```
if (query.filter) {
  const filter = '&filter=' + query.filter;
} else {
  const filter = '';
}

const [companyResponse, requestsResponse] = await Promise.all([
  // API Call "Read a company"
  $axios.$get('/companies/' + params.company),

  // API Call "List a companies requests"
  $axios.$get('/companies/' + params.company + '/requests?count=5&include=owner' + filter)
]);
```

Comment: Your declarations in the `if ... else` are *inside* those code blocks, making them local to those blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` is [block scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Examples). So, `filter` is actually `undefined` outside of the `if` braces. Notice the error in this snippet:

```js
const query = { filter: '' }

if (query.filter) {
  const filter = '&filter=' + query.filter;
} else {
  const filter = '';
}

console.log(filter)
```

To fix it, you want filter to be defined outside of a block, which can still be achieved with `const` using a ternary in this case:

```js
const filter = query.filter ? `&filter=${query.filter}` : '';

const [companyResponse, requestsResponse] = await Promise.all([
  // API Call "Read a company"
  $axios.$get('/companies/' + params.company),

  // API Call "List a companies requests"
  $axios.$get('/companies/' + params.company + '/requests?count=5&include=owner' + filter)
]);
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. I thought it was strange I couldn't solve this issue myself. But it is because I was researching the wrong issue! ‍♂️

Comment: Glad to help! Also, don't feel too bad about it - we're all prone to tunnel vision at times. Best of luck as you keep going!

Answer (score 1):

Because you defined filter in an if statement. Do this before the if statement:

```
let filter
```

Then remove "const" from the if and else blocks.